# "program to an interface not an implementation" is an important design principal to handle change. how this principal is achieved in adapter pattern?

Tags: oop, user-interface, design-patterns

**But I don't understand it, could someone explain this for me?**
"program to an interface not an implementation"  is an important design principal to handle change. how this principal is achieved in adapter pattern?

Comment: Rather than asking Stack Overflow to do your homework, go talk to your instructor and tell him or her that you did not understand that part of their lecture.

Comment: Sir thats not my homework . just i asked for information.how we can achived it in adapter pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Though your question is not 100% correct still I try to answer it. "Program to Interface not to implementation" is very root level of principle in object-oriented world. for example instead of doing

```
SpecialEmployee emp = new SpecialEmpoyee();
```

We should always do `IEmployee emp = new SpecialEmployee();`.

Below is an example of the adapter pattern using the same principle-

```
interface IBird
    {
        public void fly();
        public void makeSound();
    }

class Sparrow : IBird
{
        public void fly()
        {
          // Print "Fly"
        }
        public void makeSound()
        {
          // Print "Sound"
        }
}

interface ToyDuck
{
    // toyducks dont fly they just make
    // squeaking sound
    public void squeak();
}

class PlasticToyDuck implements ToyDuck
{
    public void squeak()
    {
        //Print "Squeak"
    }
}

class BirdAdapter implements ToyDuck
{
    // You need to implement the interface your
    // client expects to use.
    // Instead of using implementation we are programming against interface 
    // here, by using IBird instead of "new Sparrow" or something like it.
    // Further, it is an example of constructor dependency injection where we are inserting dependency "IBird" through constructor. 
    IBird bird;
    public BirdAdapter(IBird bird)
    {
        // we need reference to the object we
        // are adapting
        this.bird = bird;
    }

    public void squeak()
    {
        // translate the methods appropriately
        bird.makeSound();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Adapter pattern](https://github.com/dstar55/100-words-design-patterns-java#Adapter) allows that interface of an existing class can be used from another interface, meaning that Adapter adapts something which already exist(Adaptee) into the interface which you want(Target).

Target is an interface so you can have more implementations, one implementation is Adapter, but you can have other implementations of the target interface as well, so "program to an interface not an implementation" principle is fulfilled.